# How to detect if current working directory is a Rails project root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, command-line-interface

This is for a Rails CLI I am experimenting with and want to eventually make a gem.

Anybody have an idea for a regex or some similar way to determine if the current working directory is the rails root of a rails project?

```
def check_current_directory
  current_directory = Dir.getwd
  if current_directory # How to determine if inside Rails root?
    proceed
  else
    abort("You must be in the root of your Rails app to use this gem")
  end
end
```

Any help or idea is appreciated

Comment: Why not ignore the current directory and `chdir` to where you want to be?

Comment: @muistooshort It would be more difficult. I need the root to calculate paths for the convenience of the user. Somewhat complicated to explain, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb) is how Rails itself does that. Basically it checkes if Rails executables exist, e.g. 'bin/rails', 'script/rails'.

Comment: The link is broken. Suggestion:
http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/AppRailsLoader.html#method-i-exec_app_rails

Comment: @DanielGaytán: The link you given is also broken :(

Comment: @AjayBarot 2 years later, https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0/classes/Rails/AppRailsLoader.html

Comment: @DanielG: Welcome back mate!

Answer (score 0):

You always can get Rails project root path using `Rails.root`.

The answer is: `if current_directory == Rails.root.to_path`

Comment: And/or use `File.dirname(__FILE__)` or, in Ruby 2.0, `__dir__`.

Comment: @railscard I'm not including anything from Rails in my gem, rather trying to inject files, etc into an existing Rails app from outside the app. So I don't think I would have access to `Rails.root` but I will take a look at it. Thanks for the suggestion